# what is the command in tcpdump to get the url of an http request

Tags: tcpdump

I am trying to get tcpdump to work for getting the urls of http requests. I can't find what flags i have to use to get it. What flags do I need to get the url displayed? I don't care if it gives me the whole packet or something like that I can filter that later. I just need the url somewhere on the screen. Also I know about wireshark and all that but I want to do a real time monitoring (not saving the logs) script that lets me do things wireshark doesnt let me.

Thanks

Comment: check out this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27246/how-to-gather-dns-a-record-requests  Since it's not StackOverflow, I can't vote it as a duplicate.

Comment: URL is never transmitted. The HTTP request sends the hostname and the path separately.

Comment: I just need the packet info containing the host and the path and I could put it together.